# What sort method does chrome use for arrays greater than 10?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, quicksort

I know that Chrome used to use unstable quick sort but when I run

```
0: {name: "Dylan", friendsQty: 2, index: 8}
1: {name: "Joshua", friendsQty: 3, index: 4}
2: {name: "Mike", friendsQty: 5, index: 2}
3: {name: "Sarah", friendsQty: 5, index: 9}
4: {name: "Tyler", friendsQty: 7, index: 7}
5: {name: "Gabriella", friendsQty: 8, index: 6}
6: {name: "Andy", friendsQty: 10, index: 1}
7: {name: "Sophia", friendsQty: 10, index: 3}
8: {name: "John", friendsQty: 10, index: 5}
9: {name: "Alexa", friendsQty: 10, index: 10}
10: {name: "Henry", friendsQty: 10, index: 11}
11: {name: "Arianna", friendsQty: 10, index: 12}
```

it seems Stable because the .index are in order when I sort by friendsQty.

Comment: First of all, unstable doesn't mean it **must** mess up the sub-order. Secondly, `Array.prototype.sort` is required to be stable in modern javascript: [ECMAScript 2019 \[...\] Other updates included requiring that Array.prototype.sort be a stable sort](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-intro). You can also look at the [browser compat table on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Browser_compatibility), which includes a row for "stable sorting"

Comment: [v8 (the JavaScript engine used by Chrome) has its source posted on GitHub](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/master/src)...

Comment: Chrome sorts?  Isn't it JS that handles the sort?

Comment: Chrome's V8 engine is what interprets JavaScript and generates machine code, so Chrome V8's compiled machine code is what ends up actually performing the sort on your hardware. Until 2019, the JavaScript standard didn't require array.sort to be stable and so different JavaScript engines (like V8 vs spiderMonkey) could implement it differently.